# ASP.NET Core RC1 - WebAPI Swagger Integration - "Error" SchemaValidationMessages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I have integrated swagger in my ASP.NET Core RC1 application with following NuGet packages.

```
"Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
"Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi": "6.0.0-rc1-final"
```

Here is the code for swagger integration.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ....
        .....

        //*** Configure Swagger Document Information.
        services.ConfigureSwaggerDocument(options =>
        {
            //*** Define incremental API version.
            options.SingleApiVersion(new Info
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "TEST APIs",
                Description = "Test API Methods",
                TermsOfService = "",
            });


            //*** Assign the API - Swagger helper document.
            options.OperationFilter(new Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen.XmlComments.ApplyXmlActionComments(helperDocPath));

        });

        //*** Configure the Swagger schema settings.
        services.ConfigureSwaggerSchema(options =>
        {
            options.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings = true;
            options.ModelFilter(new Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen.XmlComments.ApplyXmlTypeComments(helperDocPath));
        });

       ....
       ....
    }

    //**** Configure Method

    private void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        ...
        ....

        //*** Add Swagger pluggins to application environment.
        app.UseSwaggerGen();
        app.UseSwaggerUi();
    }
```

The code generates the swagger documentation while accessing it locally using localhost ->  "http://localhost:8080/testapiproject/swagger/ui/index.html".

However, after deploying the code in the deployment server i am still getting the swagger document but i am getting "Error" in the bottom, upon clicking it says,

```
{"schemaValidationMessages":[{"level":"error","message":"Can't read from file http://<applicationdomainname>:8080//testapiproject/swagger/v1/swagger.json"}]}.
```

Comment: `http://:8080//testapiproject/swagger/v1/swagger.json`  this path seems to be wrong.  `hostname` is missing .  You are trying to get json from a wrong domain.

Comment: Anything other than localhost, its showing error in the bottom which is a schema validation error.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is trying to access `json` data from a wrong path. Make sure the path is configured correctly in the `testapiproject/swagger/ui/index.html"` of `swaggerui`

```
 $(function() {
        var url = window.location.search.match(/url=([^&]+)/);
        if (url && url.length > 1) {
            url = decodeURIComponent(url[1]);
        } else {
            url = "/swagger/docs/v1";     // Make sure it's not hardcoded
        }
}
```

**UPDATED for .Net Core**

I installed only `"Swashbuckle": "6.0.0-beta902"` package.

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
            services.AddSwaggerGen();
            services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(options =>
            {   
                options.SingleApiVersion(new Info
                {
                    Version = "v1",
                    Title = "test API",
                    Description = "test api for swagger",
                    TermsOfService = "None",

                });
                options.IncludeXmlComments(/* whatever tha path */);
                options.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
            });

    }
```

In the configurre mehod added just

```
          app.UseSwagger();
          app.UseSwaggerUi();   // inside this method we can pass the root path of swagger
```

It was working with localhost but not in vitural directory. So i had to add the below config to web.config then it started working.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I can't do this as I am using swagger integration for ASP.NET Core RC1 webapi project.  In RC1, you can't find the index.html.

Comment: same issue as @JAK. It is virtual

Answer (score 1):

Swager generates API docs from code comments that store in xml files. For example, comments for GatewayServer.dll will store in GatewayServer.xml. You need to upload its on deployment server.